# Is it possible to get an HTML element array item's index using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, select

I have an array of select boxes which are added programmatically. Their names are "array-ified" (see below).

```
<select name="blah[]">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<select name="blah[]">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<!-- and more... -->
```

When each is added, I want to add an `onChange` which will examine its selection. If the selection value is "A", then all of the `blah[]` selects *above* it will be set to "A". If the selection value is "B", then all of the `blah[]` selects *below* will be set to "B".

Any idea on how to do this, other than by setting the names manually when I add the fields programmatically ("blah1", "blah2", etc...)? Can jQuery get the index of each element somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) should do the trick

```
$('select').live('change', function() {
    var index = $('select').index(this);
    $('select').each(function(i) {
        if ( i < index ) {
            // do something to ones above
        }
        else ( i > index ) {
            // do something to ones below
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the other select items, assuming they're at the same level in the DOM you can can use jQuery's .nextAll()/prevAll() traversal methods.

Assuming a parent div with an id of "SelectContainer" then the following should work:

**UPDATE**

Sorry didn't ready properly, have updated to do what you asked :).

```
$('#SelectContainer').delegate('select', 'change', function() {
  var select = $(this),
      selectedValue = select.val(),
      otherSelects = select[selectedValue === 'A' ? 'prevAll' : 'nextAll']('select'),
      selectedIndex = select.children(':selected').index();

  otherSelects.val(selectedValue);
});
```

Running Example: [http://jsbin.com/ofodac/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/ofodac/edit)

I've placed stuff such as the selectedValue in variables to make it easier to follow, but to make it more concise you could easily reduce the number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/shaneburgess/zdbC3/

```
<select name="blah[]" class="select">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<select name="blah[]" class="select">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select name="blah[]" class="select">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select name="blah[]" class="select">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<!-- and more... -->
```

JS:

```
$('.select').change(function(){
    var mainIndex = 0;
     mainIndex = $(this).index();
    if($(this).val() == 'B'){


        $.each($('.select'),function(){

            if($(this).index() > mainIndex){
                $(this).val('B');
            }
        });
    }else{
        $.each($('.select'),function(){

            if($(this).index() < mainIndex){
                $(this).val('A');
            }
        });
    }
});
```